# AngularJS + Firebase (not AngularFire)

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to use the storage service of Firebase in my app with AngularJS. Every document or tutorial I had found use AngularFire Library. This library does not include storage service for AngularJS.

Is it possible to use Firebase services without use AngularFire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use `Firebase` features in `AngularJS` without `AngularFire` with no restriction but `AngularFire` is highly recommended for `AngularJS` binding with `Firebase`. Have a look at this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

There is guidance for using `Firebase` alone in `Javascript` project.